# How to call the child's parent for this specified child that already has a parent

Tags: android

This is the code:

```
public class HelpDetailsFragment extends Fragment
{
private static final String TAG = "MeMoGame";
public static HelpDetailsFragment newInstance(int index) 
{
    HelpDetailsFragment detailFragment = new HelpDetailsFragment();
    Bundle bundleArgs = new Bundle();
    bundleArgs.putInt("index", index);
    detailFragment.setArguments(bundleArgs);
    return detailFragment;
}   // newInstance()

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if(container == null)
    {
    Log.i(TAG, "Different layouts and in one this fragment's containing frame does not exist.");

        return null;
    } else {
        // I checked that container is NOT null
        Log.i(TAG, "This is the parent view that the fragment's UI should be attached to.");
    }
    View mView = new View(getActivity());
    container.addView(mView);
    return container;
}
```

This error message appears:
AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Can / will someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

When I do:

```
View mView = new View(getActivity());
TextView text = (TextView) new TextView()
mView.addView(text);
return mView;
```

I get the same error message.

My salvation lies inhere:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Context context = getActivity();

    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getActivity()
                .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int padding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, context
                .getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        // set the header
        TextView headText = new TextView(context);
        headText.setHeight(height);
        headText.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
        headText.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.details_Header);
        headText.setText(HelpScreenData.HELP_HEADERS[getCurrentIndex()]);   
        frameLayout.addView(headText);

        ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(context);
            // set detail text
            TextView detailText = new TextView(context);    
            detailText.setPadding(padding, padding + height, padding, padding);
            detailText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
             detailText.setText(HelpScreenData.HELP_DETAILS[getCurrentIndex()]);        
        scroller.addView(detailText);
    frameLayout.addView(scroller);

    return frameLayout;

}   // onCreateView()
```

An explanation would still be very welcome!

Comment: Which line causes the error? And what are you trying to do here?

Comment: There's no line number in the message.

Comment: How are you viewing the error message? Are you using the Eclipse LogCat view? If so, the line number will be later in the stacktrace. Look for lines that look like "at Xxx.Yyy()" with the name of your class and the method that causes the problem. The source file name and line number are listed in parentheses. In Eclipse, you can double click on the LogCat to jump directly to the referenced line number.

Comment: This line
((ViewGroup) mView).addView(textView);
is the culprit. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the method which contains that line of code.

Comment: I also suggest that you read [the Android Fragments Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). I don't think you implement `onCreateView()` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is you are returning the container-- `return container;` you should be returning mView in your case, the container is the actual container for the fragment in your activity layout